# jquery widget help

Tags: jquery

given:
jquery 1.3.2
jquery ui 1.7.2

I found the following jquery snippet but am having problems with it.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.widget("ui.hello", {
            options: {
                foo: "bar",
                baz: "quux"
            },
            _init: function() {
                var text = this.options.text;
                this.element.innerHTML("hello " + this.options.foo + " and " + this.options.baz);
            }
        });

        $("#thing").hello({ foo: "WORLD!" });
    });
```

***Here's the problem:***

this.options.baz); **is undefined** shouldn't it be using the default?

source:
http://blog.citrusbyte.com/2010/09/16/jquery-widgets-bringing-sanity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i ended up doing:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">       
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.widget("ui.hello", {

                _init: function() {
                    var text = this.options.text;
                    alert(this.options.baz);
                }
            });

            $.extend($.ui.hello, {
                defaults: {
                    baz: "whatever"
                }
            });
            $("#thing").hello({ foo: "WORLD!" });               
        });        
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` probably does not refer to the widget due to call context when the _init function is called. Try removing the `this.` and just refer to options like so:

```
this.element.innerHTML("hello " + options.foo + " and " + options.baz);
```